# How to use with statement in this situation?

Tags: groovy

I have something like that

```
def firstName = apiAccessor.getIdentityAPI().getUser(commentInput.authorId).firstName
def lastName = apiAccessor.getIdentityAPI().getUser(commentInput.authorId).lastName
commentVar.authorFullName = firstName + " " + lastName
```

and it works, but I want to make the same thing usign with statement.

I tried that, but don't work:

```
with(apiAccessor.getIdentityAPI().getUser(commentInput.authorId)) {
    commentVar.authorFullName = it.firstName + " " + it.lastName
}
```

How should it look like?

Comment: I think it should be `apiAccessor.getIdentityAPI().getUser(commentInput.authorId).with{commentVar.authorFullName = firstName + " " + lastName}`

Comment: Yeah, it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You call `.with{ ... }` (or `.tap{ }) right on the thing you want to use
inside the closure.  It's an delegate, so you don't even have to use`
it` (or a named argument).

You code was very close:

```
def data = [a: [b: [c: [firstName: "X", lastName: "Y"]]]]
def commentVar = [:]

data.a.b.c.with {
    commentVar.authorFullName = firstName + " " + lastName
}

assert commentVar.authorFullName == "X Y"
```